# converting android project to non-native application

Tags: android, cordova, eclipse-plugin

Can a fully developed android project be deployed ot converted as a non-native app using eclipse ide with phonegap plugin 
If so what are the necessary files to be added for the same

Answer (score 0):

> Can a fully developed android project be deployed ot converted as a non-native app using eclipse ide with phonegap plugin

Parts of the original code might survive in the form of a PhoneGap plugin, but everything else would need to be rewritten from scratch.